Including static Edge Attributes into dynamic network using networkDynamic () gives warning message
Good Evening,
I'm trying to build a dynamic network using networkDynamic() in R.  I finally got it to run and build a network, but then I kept getting over 50 warning messages.  One for each edge id ####.
I could not find this warning on a google search.  I realize something is going on with the edge attributes.  I have a node_df set up like...
x <- data.frame(start_time = rep(1648789456, 5), end_time = rep(1682571364, 5), value = as.integer(c(1,2,3,4,5)), propertyID = c("1659425840", "302027335", "1325538711", "1420839984", "35919230"), lat = c(-7.318461, -7.202876, -7.290118, -7.490271, -7.436534), long = c(-110.7441, -110.6784, -110.9157, -112.5476, -112.5974))

start_time   end_time value propertyID       lat      long
1   1648789456 1682571364     1 1659425840 -7.318461 -110.7441
2   1648789456 1682571364     2  302027335 -7.202876 -110.6784
3   1648789456 1682571364     3 1325538711 -7.290118 -110.9157
4   1648789456 1682571364     4 1420839984 -7.490271 -112.5476
5   1648789456 1682571364     5   35919230 -7.436534 -112.5974

 str(node_df)
'data.frame':   186 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ start_time : num  1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 ...
 $ end_time   : num  1.68e+09 1.68e+09 1.68e+09 1.68e+09 1.68e+09 ...
 $ value      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ propertyID : chr  "1659425840" "302027335" "1325538711" "1420839984" ...
 $ lat        : num  -7.32 -7.2 -7.29 -7.49 -7.44 ...
 $ long       : num  -111 -111 -111 -113 -113 ...

and an edge_df
y = data.frame(start_time = c(1650650617, 1650923498, 1651193217, 1651250902, 1651536477), end_time = c(1650923498, 1651167751, 1651250808, 1651516317, 1651774828), from = as.integer(c(10, 2, 1, 6, 9)), to = as.integer(c(2,1,6,9,10)), edgeID = c("C030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518", "DC030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518", "DC030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518", "DC030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518", "DC030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518"), veh_type = c("users", "users", "trucks", "trucks", "other"))

  start_time   end_time from to                               edgeID veh_type
1 1650650617 1650923498   10  2 DC030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518    users
2 1650923498 1651167751    2  1 DC030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518    users
3 1651193217 1651250808    1  6 DC030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518    users
4 1651250902 1651516317    6  9 DC030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518    users
5 1651536477 1651774828    9 10 DC030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518    users

str(edge_df)
'data.frame':   119046 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ start_time: num  1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 ...
 $ end_time  : num  1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 1.65e+09 ...
 $ from      : int  10 2 1 6 9 10 7 15 7 15 ...
 $ to        : int  2 1 6 9 10 7 15 7 15 7 ...
 $ edgeID    : chr  "DC030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518" "DC030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518" "DC030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518" "DC030E39-F95C-43CB-A9DF-2412DC984518" ...
 $ veh_type  : chr  "users" "users" "users" "users" ...

I tried running...
dyn_net <- networkDynamic(vertex.spells = node_df, edge.spells = edge_df, create.TEAs = TRUE)

OR
dyn_net <- networkDynamic(vertex.spells = node_df,edge.spells = test,
                          create.TEAs = TRUE,
                          vertex.TEA.names = c("propertyID", "prop_type_c", "lat", "long"))

OR
dyn_net <- networkDynamic(vertex.spells = node_df,edge.spells = test,
                          create.TEAs = TRUE,
                          vertex.TEA.names = c("propertyID", "prop_type_c", "lat", "long"), edge.TEA.names = c("edgeID", "veh_type"))

My outcome:
Initializing base.net of size 186 imputed from maximum vertex id in edge records
Activated TEA vertex attributes:  propertyID, prop_type_c, lat, longActivated TEA edge attributes:  edgeID, veh_typeCreated net.obs.period to describe network
 Network observation period info:
  Number of observation spells: 1 
  Maximal time range observed: 1648789456 until 1682571364 
  Temporal mode: continuous 
  Time unit: unknown 
  Suggested time increment: NA 
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

warning()

4: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  edge spell data induced an invalid spell matrix for edge TEA 'veh_type' for edge id 1861

Of course, this sample data did not reproduce the warning :-(  But this is a sample of the real data, so I'm not sure how to make it reproducible w/out the whole data set (which I can't supply). If you run networkDynamic on these small dfs, then it works.
When I took out the attributes from the original complete edge_df (last 2 columns in the edge_df) and ran networkDynamic() again, it worked with no warnings.  The vertex attributes came out just fine.  The attributes in the edge_df are not dynamic, but static.  Each edge is an ID of a specific vehicle to track and it's type.  I don't know if this changes anything.
Eventually, what I want to do is create a multilevel multiplex network based on the edge attributes.  My question then is why are the edge attributes causing the warnings, but the vertex attributes did not?  And how can I add them in the network?
I've looked at these posts:
This This This This This
plus the R documentation and vignette.
I'm not sure if you need more information or not, please let me know.
Thank you for your help in advance.
